# Hyphenate tags added to acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable

I am using acts_ as_ taggable_on in my app and have it working perfectly however I am looking for information on how to make one modification.

At present if I enter a tag which includes spaces, the tag is saved with these spaces and so to view all records with this tag I have something like:

`http://myapp.local/tag/this%20tag%20has%20spaces`

How can I hyphenate tags when they are first saved by acts_ as_ taggable_on so that the tag is stored as this-tag-has-spaces?

I can substitute the values as follows, but how do I do this before acts_ as_ taggable_on takes over and saves the tag list?

`tag.downcase.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,'-').gsub(/-{2,}/,'-')`

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By taking advantage of the fact that [acts_as_taggable_on_steroids](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids) exposes a `tag_list` accessor that can be written to, here is what I did on one of my models.  I 
assume you could do something similar:

```
class MyTaggableObject < ActiveRecord::Base 
  acts_as_taggable

  before_validation :clean_up_tags

  # Clean up tag formatting
  def clean_up_tags
    # Make lowercase 
    self.tag_list.map!(&:downcase) 

    # Replace any non-word ([^\w]) characters with a hyphen
    self.tag_list.map! {|tag| tag.gsub(/[^\w]+/i,'-')} 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn.force_parameterize = true
```

to an initializer.

Comment: this is the new and easier way of doing it.